# C++ How to quote user input?

Tags: c++

How do I quote an integer that the user inputted along with the result.
Example, I'm trying to make this code print, The number "12" in binary format is "1100"

My code;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void decimalToBinary();

int main()
{
    decimalToBinary();

    return 0;
} 

void decimalToBinary()
{
    int array[32];
    int number, index;

    cout << "Enter a number to convert to binary: ";    
    cin>>number;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "The number " << number << " in binary format is ";

    for(index=0; number>0; index++)    
    {    
    
        array[index]=number%2;
        number= number/2;  
    
    }

    for(index=index-1 ;index>=0 ;index--)    
    {    
    
        cout << array[index];
    
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a \ (escape sequence, the same method used for \n, or \t)to show that the quotes are to be ignored:

```cpp
cout << "The number \" " << number << " \" in binary format is ";
```

Comment: shouldnt there be << on either side of number?

Comment: Yeah, that's called an escape sequence, in c++ the escape character is the backslash, for example a new line character is `\n`

Comment: This will add spaces inside of quotes. Space-less version: `"foo \"" << number << "\" bar"`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat should of put that, but it still answers the question.

Comment: Thank you! I learn something new everyday

Comment: @FindMeTheArrayGuy no problem.